# wrong plot poincare in mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica

My poincare function works well and can produce correct value when only using function.
But it will goes wrong when I try to plot it.

I don't know where I was wrong maybe in the plot? IDK
could you please help me to debug it
here is my code:
`poincare[x0_] := NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1/4*x[t]*(1 - (x[t])^2) + 1/5*Sin[t],x[0] == x0}, {x[2 Pi]}, {t, 0, 30}] Plot[poincare[x], {x, -2, 2}]` 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nHnTF.png)

Comment: Does this do exactly what you want? `poincare[x0_]:=NDSolveValue[{x'[t]==1/4*x[t]*(1-(x[t])^2) +1/5*Sin[t],x[0]==x0},x[2 Pi],{t,0,30}];Plot[poincare[x0],{x0,0,30}]` Check that character by character to find all my changes. Then try undoing those changes, a single character at a time, and see where it breaks. There are still bits of this that don't seem to be the "usual" way of writing this and which worry me.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you can't use NDSolve if you don't know both x0 and t at the same time.
But I noticed that you put x[2 Pi], and I'm not sure if you're trying to set x0 = 2 Pi.
Anyway, there are two different ways to extract plots.

1- Unfixed x0

```
poincare1 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1/4*x[t]*(1 - (x[t])^2) +1/5*Sin[t], x[0] == x0}, x, {t, 0, 30}, {x0}]

Plot[Evaluate[Table[poincare1[x0][t], {x0, -2, 2, 0.5}]], {t, 0, 30}]
```

2- Fixed x0 = 2 Pi

```
poincare2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 1/4*x[t]*(1 - (x[t])^2) +1/5*Sin[t], x[0] == x0}, x, {t, 0, 30}, {x0}]
Plot[Evaluate[poincare2[2*\[Pi]][t]], {t, 0, 30}]
```